Using the Firebase CLI with a non-default DB
When using Firebase there is a CLI command to get the contents of some collection in a DB.
It goes like this:
firebase database:get /DBPath-tocollection --output myfile.json
and it works very well.
The above works when dealing with the default database.
But here is my question: what is the command to use when dealing with a non-default database ?

According to the documentation on managing multiple Realtime Database instances, you can specify a non-default database by specifying the --instance option to the CLI.
